# Asp.net 1.1 wizard?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is there any wizard controls available for ASP.NET 1.1????

Please let me know if you guys have any valuable links.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the Wizard control was added in ASP.Net 2.0. You can create a comparable look-alike with Panels and buttons